# select count (if(exp,t,f)) as number

Tags: mysql

I have two table for mysql

tb1:`id_q(pk),q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10`

tb2:`id(pk),id_q(fk),ip,ans`

and my query

```
select count(if(q1==-1 and q2==-1 and q3==-1 and q4==-1 and q5==-1 and q6==-1 and q7==-1 and q8==-1 and
q9==-1 and q10==-1)) as number from tb1 where id=number
```

and

```
select count(ans (if(ans==1))) ans q1 ,count(ans (if(ans==2))) ans q2,count(ans (if(ans==3))) ans q3,
count(ans (if(ans==4))) ans q4,count(ans (if(ans==5))) ans q5,count(ans (if(ans==6))) ans q6 ,
count(ans (if(ans==7))) ans q7,count(ans (if(ans==8))) ans q8,count(ans (if(ans==9))) ans q9,
count(ans (if(ans==10))) ans q10 from tb1,tb2 where tb1.id_q=tb2.id_q
```

??
I want two query in one query?

Comment: I have no idea what your problem/issue/question/query is. Please elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: I have 2 tables and 2 queries ?? The answer is YES!! Vote over here please

Answer (score 1):

For SQL-Server, Count(Column_Name) will count the total number of rows that are not Null; therefore you could compute the first expression with a Case statement returning 1 for True or Null for False:

```
select count(Case When (q1=-1 and q2=-1 and q3=-1 and q4=-1 and q5=-1 and q6=-1 and q7=-1 and q8=-1 and q9=-1 and q10=-1) Then 1 Else Null End) as number from tb1
```

A second possibility would be to use the SUM() function with a Case statement returning either 1 or 0:

```
select Sum(Case When (q1=-1 and q2=-1 and q3=-1 and q4=-1 and q5=-1 and q6=-1 and q7=-1 and q8=-1 and q9=-1 and q10=-1) Then 1 Else 0 End) as number from tb1
```

You do the same for your second query. (And of course, you have to use the proper instruction for doing a Case statement on MySQL if the syntax is different.)

I forgot to mention that you need to use the proper equality operator `=` instead of `==` in the Case statement.